# What is the correct root for Jetbrains Hub, UpSource & YouTrack with LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm looking for the correct root to use for Jetbrains Hub, UpSource & YouTrack with LetsEncrypt. I have all three of these located in their own folder in `/opt/`

With certbot, I am using the following command to generate a certificate:

`certbot certonly --webroot -w <root> -d hub.example.com`

I assumed the root would be `/opt/hub/apps/hub/web` yet I get an error when certbot is trying to locate the certificate in the `.well-known` folder indicating the root is incorrect.

I'd rather not create a *"fake"* root in `/var/www/jetbrains` and keep everything in their own folder if possible.

(I could not use the tags `jetbrains-hub` `youtrack` & `upsource` as they do not exist and I do not have enough reputation, if anyone would be so kind, thank you).

Comment: Are you not using a web server with these applications?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have setup all three with a proxy in nginx in according with the Jetbrains documentation. Example: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.5/proxy-configuration.html

Comment: In that case you can just add an appropriate `location` in the nginx configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sadly this would require me to push a request for the `.well-known` folder to another root if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You say you'd rather not create a "fake" root, but it vastly simplifies management and it works across everything, regardless of application or domain, so I'm going to ignore that request for this answer.

Include

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/www/letsencrypt;
    index index.html;
    location = /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =444;
}
```

in the server block for each application and tell certbot to use /var/www/letsencrypt as the webroot. I have this in a template I include in dozens of `server{}` blocks for various domains and applications. You can leave off the `index` if you want, but I like to put "Go away." index.html files everywhere just to make sure auto-indexing doesn't happen.